# Using unionfs or similar as root file system in Linux?

Tags: mount, root-filesystem, union-mount, unionfs

After building Linux From Scratch several times I realized that package management is really a hard thing to do. After thinking for some time, I came across an idea. My idea is to install all packages into separate directories, then combine them into one file system and mount as root (required). Also, I want to attach and detach packages without a reboot (optional, preferred).

How can I do this from scratch (or with a package)? (No problem if I need to program (C or C++ preferred))

Comment: You need to understand how your system starts, when filesystem access is first required, and how that's done. How early in the startup will you be able to do your `unionfs` magic (and make the packages available)?

Comment: @waltinator I will be happy to learn that. Any information about that?

Comment: Click on my username and read my "Dual Boot" advice. Read all 4 of the Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @waltinator None contains any information about Linux.

Comment: Gentoo allows you to learn compile and customize everything as much as you want.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov But I want a DIY distro.